# Visual Studio 2010/2012: when Stop Debugging on breakpoint hit debugged process hangs and is unkillable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Happens with some occasion.
Running Windows 8 x64, with Visual Studio 2012 Professional (also happened before in VS 2010).
C# console project being debugged with "Enable native code debugging".

Pressing F5, debugging some code, reaching breakpoints, etc. then pressing Shift+F5 (Stop Debugging) and the Visual Studio does not return to editing mode as normally, it just hangs for a while and then gives an option to terminate the hanging operation (dialog window **"A remote operation is taking longer than expected"** with progress bar and Terminate button). If I don't click to terminate, it stays there just updating the progress bar.
If I click to terminate the operation, VS returns back to editable mode but the debugged process is still visible in Task Manager and its not killable. This pending debug process locks certain files it uses (e.g. DLLs) so further rebuild is not possible. The only way to kill this process is to restart the machine.

Interestingly it happens when the breakpoints are reached in debugged code and debugging is performed step by step. If I just run the debugging process without breakpoints then the hang does not occur.

Solutions in the following thread didn't help: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/504538/

Comment: I think this is related to networking IO that I'm working with.

Comment: I had faced the same issue due to different framework versions. I was using external assemblies which were using older framework. And JACOB's answer did the trick for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

We have faced similar issues before using 2010, but couldn't figure out the root cause yet.

The workaround was to run the process separately (console, double click the .exe) and do [Debug->Attach To Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3.aspx).
 *Note:* If you wanna debug start up code then this might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing some serious unaccountable issues regarding file locks and weird behaviour of the debugger a while ago. I solved them by activating application experience service. I don't know why but after activating it all my problems regarding debugging silently vanished...

Answer (score 0):

I came across a *similar* hanging problem and solved it. Trying it *may* heal your wound (it is for windows forms, but since you're on console, it is worth giving a try):

[Windows Form Won't Display in Debug Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955864/windows-form-wont-display-in-debug-mode/39591028#39591028)

Please let me know if it works or not.